# Convert pixel to percentage using javascript

Tags: javascript, function, width, pixel, percentage

I have a table header's width in pixel. on click of a function i need to convert pixel to percentage.

```
<th field="Column1" id="Column1" noresize="true" width="100px">
    <label id="Column1" onclick="getCustomGridColName(this.id,'inner__fghgh');" style="cursor:pointer; font-family: Times; font-size:12pt;">
        Column1
    </label>
</th>
```

Comment: Percentage of what? The table? The page?

Comment: Percentage of what exactly. Relative to the screen, the closest parent, another element, it self ?

Comment: not percentage of another element.. same element itself.. 100px = ?% using script

Comment: I think you need to read up on the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), it needs to be a percentage ***of*** something, in CSS with absolute or relative positioning, that would normally be the closest parent.

Answer (score 18):

percentage is a relative value.

with one value like `100px` you cannot make a percentage.

you need to have relative value like screenWidth (for suppose) `1366px` so that you will get percentage of that value.

```
var pixels = 100;
var screenWidth = window.screen.width;
var percentage = ( screenWidth - pixels ) / screenWidth ; // 0.92%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Transform pixel in percentage
/* - totalpx: Total of pixels depending on the width or height, could be 1920.0 or 1080.0, 1280.0 or 720.0, etc...
     respectively.
   - px: the pixel desidered to be converted.
   - ItIsHeight: boolean to know if is axis x or y ot make the correct calculation.
   - BaseOfConversionWidth & BaseOfConversionHeight: the base of conversion from the original pixel are take it, if
     the design is HD ready then will be 1280.0 and 720.0, if is full HD then will be 1920.0 and 1080.0, etc... */
public Double TransformPercentage(Double Totalpx, Double px, boolean ItIsHeight, double BaseOfConversionWidth, double BaseOfConversionHeight) {
    if (ItIsHeight)
        return (px / BaseOfConversionHeight) * Totalpx;
    else
        return (px / BaseOfConversionWidth) * Totalpx;
}
```