# jq- how to convert pixel value into percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a part of my code here i got the value in a variable p as a pixel value but i want its percentage(%) value

```js
p = parseInt(e.clientX - base.offset().left) ;
                $('#' + base[0].id + '_value').val(p);

                base.css('width', p);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807021/convert-pixel-to-percentage-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixel is a static measurement, while percent and EM are relative measurements. The size of an EM or percent depends on its parent. If the text size of body is 16 pixels, then 150% or 1.5 EM will be 24 pixels (1.5 * 16). Look at CSS Units for more measurement units.

Comment: try to calculate. 16 px = 100%