# Why width style value not show in input?

Tags: javascript, input, onclick, styles, return-value

I'm trying to take the width from the "demo" div and put it in the "input number" value. I can not figure out where I made a mistake...

```js
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("poster"),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    width = style.getPropertyValue('width');
  
  document.getElementById("demo").value = width;
}
```

```html
 
<div id="poster" style="width:35px;height:45px;background-color:blue;"></div>

<input id="demo" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">

<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue because `width` value is `35px` so you should remove `px` before assign it to `document.getElementById("demo").value` to be number as soon as your `input` type is `number` as following code

```
<div id="poster" style="width:35px;height:45px;background-color:blue;"></div>
<input id="demo" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementById("poster"),
        style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
        width = style.getPropertyValue('width').match(/\d+/);

      document.getElementById("demo").value = width;
    }
</script>
```

if you want to get width number as it is without unit eg. `35px` or `35%` will get `35` you can use the following code:

```
  <div id="poster" style="width:35px;height:45px;background-color:blue;"></div>
<input id="demo" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">
<select id="unit" >
  <option >none</option>
  <option value="%">%</option>
  <option value="px">px</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementById("poster"),
        width = element.style["width"].match(/\d+/),
        unit = element.style["width"].match(/[^\d]+/);
        document.getElementById("unit").value = unit
        document.getElementById("demo").value = width;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In some div elements I have 300px, and in some 30%, if I put the percentages I always return in pixels. How can I get only the number 300 or 30 from the width but not convert it to pixsele?

Comment: Work grat :) I nead now text from width = px or % so i can put in form, and use if()..., how?

Comment: Ahmed. I need to use ("demo"). Value = parseFloat (width); to get the numbers in the imput number. For example, width = "35px" I get only 35 without px or %. inside my code besides imput number I have the option to select px or %, so I should also get text from width px or %.  widouth numbers so i put in select value.

Comment: I need separate variables one for numbers (35) and one for letters (px or %) of width. 35 insert value in input number, and px or % insert value in opstion select.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `width` to `number` because you use `input number` not text. Actually, your `width` is a string (35px).

```js
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("poster"),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    width = style.getPropertyValue('width');

  document.getElementById("demo").value = parseFloat(width);
}
```

```html
<div id="poster" style="width:35px;height:45px;background-color:blue;"></div>

<input id="demo" type="number" placeholder="0" min="" max="" step="0.1">

<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: In some div elements I have 300px, and in some 30%, if I put the percentages I always return in pixels. How can I get only the number 300 or 30 from the width but not convert it to pixsele?

Comment: This may help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807021/convert-pixel-to-percentage-using-javascript

Comment: Not helping, Can i get percentage number form style width not just px?

Comment: Nope, getPropertyValue always returns px, you have to convert px to percentage

Comment: With parseFloat(width); i get only nuber, how i can get only text px or %, so i can use if()?

Comment: Don't use screen width but the container width.
`(containerWidth - pixels) / containerWidth`